# Azerty keyboard switches back to qwerty on startup. HP 850

Tags: keyboard, language, qwerty

On my HP laptop I have the AZERTY layout, however the keyboard is QWERTY when typing. I changed it to AZERTY through control panel and it didn't do anything. After restarting the laptop it switched to AZERTY as needed but only for a brief moment. It switched back to QWERTY moments later. What can cause this and how can I permanently change it to AZERTY?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?